# Symfony4 - isXmlHttpRequest showing wrong data

Tags: symfony

I'm not sure how to explain my problem.
I have a controller that has this piece of code to check if URL is accessed using ajax or not.

```
        //check if ajax request
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
```

If url is accessed using ajax it's returning JSON if not it's returning view. 
When I access this URL in chrome it's showing right data(view) but if I move to for example google.com and click "back arrow" in Chrome's UI, it takes me back to my URL but now it's showing JSON.

Everything is working fine in Safari, so I'm not sure where is the problem and what to do...

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Same code works fine on Symfony 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix: `@Cache(vary={"X-Requested-With"})`